# Numba messes up dtype when broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, numba, array-broadcasting

I want to safe storage by using small dtypes. However when I add or multiply a number to an array numba changes the dtype to int64:

Pure Numpy

In:

```
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a+1
f()
```

Out:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

Now with numba:

In:

```
@njit
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a+1
f()
```

Out:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

One solution is to replace a+1 with a+np.ones(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype) but I cannot imagine something uglier.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Weird, so `+1` changes the dtype `int64` -> `uint8`

Comment: Well, it goes the other way around, but yes. I guess it is because the 1 needs to be extended to an array in order to be added to a. In numpy the dtype of that new array is automatically adjusted to a. Numba just uses the standard of int64. And when you add to arrays the bigger dtype survives.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `uint8` -> `int64`. Hmm..that's probably just it - good thinking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the simplest thing is to just add two `np.uint8`:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a + np.uint8(1)
print(f().dtype)
```

Output:

```
uint8
```

I find this more elegant than changing the type of the full array or working with `np.ones` or `np.full`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.ones_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html):

```
@njit
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a + np.ones_like(a)
f()
```

Output:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

...or [`np.full_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full_like.html):

```
@njit
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a + np.full_like(a, 100)
f()
```

Output:

```
array([101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, this is probably because numba's default type is `int64`, and the smaller dtype `uint8` gets converted to the larger `int64`.

Why not just convert it?

```
@njit
def f():
    a=np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return (a+1).astype('uint8')
f()
```

Output:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

That's less ugly than `a+np.ones(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)`. ;)

Comment: Thats a possibility if you have many arrays, but if the individual array is huge, I do not think that this would save any memory. Because it needs a lot of space to compute the a+1 part, right?

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this if you are willing to make your function accept inputs. I rewrote your function using the `signature_or_function` argument of `njit`:

```py
@numba.njit(signature_or_function='uint8[:](uint8)')
def f(x):
    a = np.ones(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    return a+x

f(1)
# array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

Some documentation on [numba signatures](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/types.html#signatures). If you define signatures, numba will compile a specialized function for each unique signature and try to use a compatible pre-compiled signature for anything for which a signature isn't explicitly defined. The signature there tells it that it will return an array if unsigned 8-bit integers (`'uint8[:]'`) and take an input of an unsigned 8-bit integer value.

Note that in this case, I had to make the function accept an input because numba seems to default to treating integer literals (e.g., the `1` of `a + 1`) as `int64` values, but if you specify that the input to the function is a `uint8` and you don't make a more permissive signature, then when you compile and run the function, it will treat your input as `uint8` and not up-convert since it doesn't need to.